# Why can't XCode find GoogleMobileAds

Tags: ios, xcode, module, frameworks, admob

I know this has been asked before and I've reviewed the other answers. I have closed XCode and run pod install multiple times. When I re-open XCode I use the .xcworkspace project file. And I have checked that my `target -> Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries` section includes `GoogleMobileAds.framework`
So why am I still getting `No such module 'GoogleMobileAds'` as a build error?
(Note I did used to get a link error previously and following some other stackoverflow Q&A I deleted the directories that were showing up in link errors from the Library Search Paths.)

Comment: I think I had a GoogleService-Info-2.plist because I had one in my downloads folder from another project. I deleted the other one, re-downloaded, deleted the plist file in my project, and re-added the fresh plist file. I also dragged the GoogleMobileAds.framework over into my Target->Buid Phases-> Link Binary with Libraries section. Eventually I found the GoogleMobileAds but then got linker errors with Firebase Analytics. So much futile effort there that I just created a new project from scratch. That's ultimately what worked. Sorry I couldn't fix the original project for others stumbling here

Answer (score 0):

Try build your project once. It will first compile the pods project(thus compiling the GoogleMobileAds framework), then stop the build when it starts to compile your swift code, or you can let it finish if you want. After that, you should be able to see the framework and use it for auto-completion. I have personally found this much faster than to wait for Xcode to pre-build and index.